# Change the font color of a cell if other cells are not empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, fonts

How can I write the following code expression in Excel? What I want is to be able to change the font color of a cell if other cells are not empty.

Expression:

> > if cell A1, A2 & A3 are not empty change the font color of Cell B1

I tried...

```
=IF(A1:A3 <> "",  B1.Font.Color = vbRed)
```

...but it doesn't work, all I see is `#NAME?`

Again, what I want is to change the font color of a cell based on the state of other cells.

Comment: Use Conditional Formatting on B1.  A formula by itself cannot change the format of a cell.  You can use a formula that returns TRUE/FALSE in Conditional Formatting that will.  The formula will be: `=AND(A1:A3<>"")`

Comment: `=AND(A1:A3<>"") in Conditional Formatting` did the trick. I have never used Conditional Formatting before. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean that **all** cells must be non-empty to get *BLUE* or **any** of the cells non-empty to get *BLUE* ??

Answer (score 1):

`B2.Font.Color = vbRed` is not a value the cell can return, it is VBA code that can't be used in a formula.

In this case, you will want to use [conditional formatting](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/applying-conditional-formatting-in-excel-2007/).